# How to get i18n from different location with good performance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

[Link for sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/PYZxcI5yTNuA0fEern9s?p=preview)

```
Sample File
```

Here I created some sample application for locale..In that application
I created only few Json file in same location...one for English another one for french..which is working fine.. In future I will Create common and moduleName folders..(i.e) Common, registration, Login, etc...  Every Folder contains few Json file one for English another one for french.. In common folder I will put common label name only and In others label's I put corresponding folder.. How to achieve this with good performance?
thanks,

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/PYZxcI5yTNuA0fEern9s?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend angular-translate for this. i do not think it's a good idea to implement something from scratch which is already there for a  long time. there is also a plugin for angular-translate with static files.

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Asynchronous-loading

Comment: +1 . @miniclip : i use angular-translate. ( https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate )
very easy to use, you can change the langage on the fly, translate in the view or controller. try it and don't wast time rebuilding  the wheel

Comment: @Patrick Kelleter for few label i vl get from come directory and other i vl get from corresponding directory that time how it vl work??

Comment: Eg:- firstname, middlename, lastname i vl get from common.. non unique label i vl get from login/registration/ etc.. based on module name folder..